# How can I control initialization of an angular directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that is used as a form control. This directive is hidden in a modal dialog and is shown when the user clicks a button to show the form. Since this directive connects to some web services, I don't want it to initialize unless the user clicks the button and the form displays (to prevent unnecessary web service calls). So, what I'm looking for is a good way for the parent controller to trigger the directive to execute some init code. Here is an example:

```
App.controller('parentCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.onButtonClick = function onButtonClick() {
    // tell directive to init somehow
  };
}]);

App.directive('myDirective', function() {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {},
  controller: function($scope, myService) {
    function init() {
      myService.getData().then(function(value) { //do init stuff });
    }
  }
});
```

Assume the template for parentCtrl contains a tag .

Answer (score 12):

Tagging your element in an `ng-if` will prevent the directive from initializing before it's needed. (`scope.loadModal` should be false by default)

```
<my-directive ng-if='loadModal'></mydirective>
```

Note: Setting `scope.loadModal = false` after showing the directive once will *unload* the directive from your DOM. Setting it back to true would reload the directive resulting in another http request.

Comment: This works, but doesn't allow me to trigger the init function again, unless I toggle the loadModal variable, which isn't ideal. This could be how I end up doing it though. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, setting loadModal to true doesn't seem to define the isolated scope variables. Any code using those in the parent gets undefined errors.

Comment: `ng-if` creates a new scope, so if you're passing variables into your directive I would suggest namespacing them. e.g. `<my-directive ng-if='loadModal' variable='something.variable'></my-directive>`.

Comment: So far the best way I've found to do this is by using a $broadcast('formShowing') in the parent and $on('formShowing', function() {}) in the directive. Thoughts on this strategy?

Comment: That sounds okay; though personally I'd probably go with `ng-if`